# Mention official Ubuntu flavors in the off-topic close reason

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Currently, one of the off-topic close reason's text is the following:

> **This is not about Ubuntu.** Questions about **other Linux distributions** can be asked on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), those about **Windows** on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), those about **Apple products** on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and **generic programming questions** on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Can it be changed to mention official Ubuntu Flavors instead of just Ubuntu? This is a suggestion of mine:

> **This is not about an [official Ubuntu flavor](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).** Questions about **other Linux distributions** can be asked on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), those about **Windows** on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), those about **Apple products** on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and **generic programming questions** on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

I just changed the first sentence to say "official Ubuntu flavor" instead of just "Ubuntu" with a link to the [on-topic help center artcle](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just wondering, does the default Ubuntu count as an official flavor? I prefer your wording to "Ubuntu or its official flavors" or whatever, and I think it would be understood regardless though. +1 to this FR

Comment: @Zanna The help centre lists Ubuntu as an official flavor. My other reasoning is to keep as short as possible in case there's a character limit on the close reasons.